# requireJS with fileupload plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, requirejs

In requirejs, we can set the name for js via this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js'
    }
});
```

And use it with this:

```
requirejs(['jquery'],function ($) {
    //loaded and can be used here now.
});
```

But for some plugin like fileuploads required a number of js files. Their document shows how to use it with requirejs: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-use-jQuery-File-Upload-with-RequireJS

But, how can I manage to put them all into one name?

```
requirejs(['jquery','fileupload'],function ($) {
    //all fileupload js has been loaded and ready to use
});
```

So that when I require fileupload, it will load all the required js without requiring them one by one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a meta-module that imports all the necessary resources and bundles them together, the end modules then become transitive dependencies that are loaded implicitly:

**fileupload.js**

```
define(['jquery',
        'js/jquery.iframe-transport',
        'js/jquery.fileupload-ui'
], function () {
  // all needed dependencies loaded
});
```

When you require `fileupload` you ensure all the needed dependencies are present.