# loading blue-imp fileupload with requirejs throws error on blobSlice

Tags: jquery, file-upload, requirejs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm loading the fileupload plugin with requirejs

I was loading the plugin as follows:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'jquery.iframe-transport',
        'jquery.fileupload-ui'
    ], function(
        jquery,
        itransport,
        fileupload_ui
    )
    {
```

This stackoverflow question confirms this:

[requireJS with fileupload plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272773/requirejs-with-fileupload-plugins)

The problem occurs when "load-image-meta" is executed at those lines:

```
    loadImage.blobSlice = hasblobSlice && function () {
```

[image]

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'blobSlice' of undefined.**

This is because loadImage is being passed as an argument as undefined and I can't figure out the reason once we already defined the dependecy on `line 23`.

can someone help me?

### ADITIONAL INFORMATION (below)

Here is the list of paths defined for each plugin at requirejs.config.paths

```
 'jquery.postmessage-transport': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/cors/jquery.postmessage-transport',
        'jquery.xdr-transport': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport',
        'jquery.ui.widget': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget',
        'jquery.fileupload': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
        'jquery.fileupload-process': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process',
        'jquery.fileupload-validate': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate',
        'jquery.fileupload-image': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image',
        'jquery.fileupload-audio': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio',
        'jquery.fileupload-video': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-video',
        'jquery.fileupload-ui': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui',
        'jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui',
        'jquery.fileupload-angular': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-angular',
        'jquery.iframe-transport': './bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport',
 'blueimp-canvas-to-blob': './bower_components/blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob',
        'canvas-to-blob': './bower_components/blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob',
        'load-image': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image',
        'load-image-ios': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-ios',
        'load-image-orientation': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-orientation',
        'load-image-meta': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta',
        'load-image-exif': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif',
        'load-image-exif-map': './bower_components/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif-map',
        'tmpl': './bower_components/blueimp-tmpl/js/tmpl'
```

this is the dependency list of each file

```
jquery.postmessage-transport
---'jquery'

jquery.xdr-transport
---'jquery'


jquery.ui.widget.js
---'jquery'


jquery.fileupload.js
---'jquery',
---'jquery.ui.widget'


jquery.fileupload-process.js
---'jquery',
---'./jquery.fileupload' ***


jquery.fileupload-validate
---'jquery',
----'./jquery.fileupload-process' ***


jquery.fileupload-image
    'jquery',
    'load-image',
    'load-image-meta',
    'load-image-exif',
    'load-image-ios',
    'canvas-to-blob',
    './jquery.fileupload-process' ****

jquery.fileupload-audio
    'jquery',
    'load-image',
    './jquery.fileupload-process'



jquery.fileupload-video.js
    'jquery',
    'load-image',
    './jquery.fileupload-process'


jquery.fileupload-ui
    'jquery',
    'tmpl',
    './jquery.fileupload-image',
    './jquery.fileupload-audio',
    './jquery.fileupload-video',
    './jquery.fileupload-validate'


jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui
    'jquery',
    './jquery.fileupload-ui'


jquery.fileupload-angular
     'jquery',
    'angular',
    './jquery.fileupload-image',
    './jquery.fileupload-audio',
    './jquery.fileupload-video',
    './jquery.fileupload-validate'


jquery.iframe-transport
    'jquery'


blueimp-canvas-to-blob
// duplicated with key "canvas-to-blob" to match jquery.fileupload-image dependency key

load-image
    NO DEPS

load-image-ios
    'load-image'

load-image-orientation
    'load-image'

load-image-meta
    'load-image'

load-image-exif
    'load-image'
    'load-image-meta'

load-image-exif-map
    'load-image',
    'load-image-exif'

tmpl
   NO DEPENDENCIES
```

Comment: You definitely need to set `load-image` as dependency in shims for blueimp

Comment: Yup, you are right. After setting up the shim forcing the dependencie to load before the module it worked fine. But that's a weird problem because i started a new project and did everthing as i've made previously and without setting up the shim it was still working

Comment: i guess it was just luck or resources was not loading async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ant_Ti mentioned on it's comment to my question i had to force requirejs to load `load-image` before loading `load-image-meta` for that reason I added the following piece of code to my requirejs.config.shim object:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery.fileupload-ui': {
            deps: ['load-image']
        }
    }
});
```

this ensures that when we try to load `jquery.fileupload-ui`, `load-image` will be already available.